# Rational cohomology of formal multiplicative group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, group-cohomology, formal-groups

Let $\hat{\mathbb G}$ be a formal group over a field $k$, and let $V$ be a finite dimensional algebraic representation of $\hat{\mathbb G}$ (meaning we have fixed a homomorphism of algebraic groups $\rho:\hat{\mathbb G}\to\operatorname{GL}(V)$ over $k$).

I would like to consider the **rational cohomology of $\hat{\mathbb G}$ with coefficients in $V$**, denoted $H^\ast(\hat{\mathbb G},V)$.  By definition, this is the cohomology of the complex whose $p$-cochains are the additive group of regular functions
$$f:\overbrace{\hat{\mathbb G}\times\cdots\times\hat{\mathbb G}}^{p\text{ times}}\to V$$
and whose differential is given by the usual formula
$$(\delta f)(t_1,\ldots,t_p)=\rho(t_1)f(t_2,\ldots,t_p)-f(t_1t_2,t_3,\ldots,t_p)+f(t_1,t_2t_3,t_4,\ldots,t_p)-\cdots$$
I presume much must be known about the resulting cohomology groups $H^\ast(\hat{\mathbb G},V)$, but I do not know where to look.

I believe I can show that $H^\ast(\hat{\mathbb G}_{\mathrm{m}},k_{\mathrm{std}}^{\otimes n})=0$ for integers $n\ne 0$, where $\hat{\mathbb G}_{\mathrm{m}}$ is the formal multiplicative group and $k_{\mathrm{std}}$ is its standard representation.  Is this a known result for which there exists a canonical reference?  It looks like I need this result for some specific application, and I'd like to get a feeling for what is known in this area.

Comment: For a flat affine group scheme $G$ over a ring $A$, the "Hochschild cohomology" functors for (functorial) linear representations of $G$ on $A$-modules are the derived functors of "$G$-invariants" (see Lemma B.2.3 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf for a proof).  That proves vanishing of higher Hochschild cohomology of $A$-tori $T$ (on $A$-modules with a linear $T$-action) via exactness of "$T$-invariants" (due to gradings over an etale cover of $A$ splitting $T$). Complete reducibility of $\widehat{\mathbf{G}}_m$-actions over $k$ holds in char. $p$, but not in char. 0...

Comment: [The "problem" is that in char. 0, $\widehat{\mathbf{G}}_m \simeq \widehat{\mathbf{G}}_a$.]  Note that you're using the notation "$k$" for the field and the cohomological degree. Do you want only ${\rm{char}}(k)>0$? Anyway, a very general functor-based reference on Hochschild cohomology  over fields is provided inside the massive tome of Demazure-Gabriel on algebraic groups, but I don't remember offhand if they address the case of formal groups in there (and that book can be a bit daunting to navigate).

Comment: Minor pedantic point: since $\widehat{\mathbf{G}}_m$ is not a scheme but only a formal scheme (e.g., the comultiplication involves a completed tensor product at the coordinate ring level), one shouldn't speak of a map $\rho: \widehat{\mathbf{G}}_m \rightarrow {\rm{GL}}(V)$ being one of "algebraic groups" but rather as a map of formal group schemes (where the target is an ordinary group scheme viewed as a formal scheme).